# A Tribute to Alex Trebek

Tags: word, connect-wall

This is a very sad day for puzzlers and Jeopardy! lovers alike. I decided to create this puzzle to commemorate Alex because he is the reason I got into making puzzles.

This is a typical connect wall, so it has 4 sets of 4 words that will lead you to the final word I have in mind. I picked the final word for a specific reason relating to Jeopardy! and Alex Trebek. It is a pretty easy connect wall, as it is my first time making one.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BLOCK | BOOM | BAXTER | HOUSE |
| LEWIS | RED | DOWN | GREEN |
| HOME | CORN | DAVE | LONDON |
| MYTH | MARTIN | MINT | DOCTOR |

Comment: +1... For Alex.

Comment: Hey, don't do yourself down by assuming we'll all find this 'pretty easy'! I'm only confident about one category for sure right now (and wondering if some specific US-centric knowledge is key to linking the various names in the grid...), so to my mind this is far from 'pretty easy' right now! :) (PS And well done for taking the plunge and making your first one!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came up with different groupings but the same final answer as hexomino:

> **BUSTER** : BLOCK, MYTH, DAVE, BAXTER (Blockbuster, Mythbusters, [Dave & Busters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_%26_Buster%27s), [Buster Baxter](https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Baxter))
>  **PEPPER** : RED, CORN, MINT, DOCTOR (Red pepper, Peppercorn, Peppermint, Dr. Pepper)
>  **TOWN** : DOWN, BOOM, HOME, HOUSE (Downtown, Boom town, Hometown, Townhouse)
>  **WRITER**: MARTIN, LONDON, LEWIS, GREEN (George R.R. Martin, Jack London, C.S. Lewis, [John Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Green_(author)))

"Final answer":

> **GHOST**: Ghostbusters, Ghost pepper, Ghost town, Ghost writer

Alex Trebek connection (as deduced by hexomino and Josh Crozier):

> G.H.O.S.T is an acronym standing for "greatest host of syndicated TV", as answered by [James Holzhauer in this video](https://youtu.be/Svw6NCnuIkE?t=53)

Comment: This seems better!

Answer (score 23):

I think the connections are as follows

> **1.** Words connected to **BUSTER** - BLOCK(buster), [(Buster) BAXTER](https://arthur.fandom.com/wiki/Buster_Baxter), [HOUSE(buster)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Housebuster), MYTH(buster).
>  **2.** Words connected to **TOWN** - BOOM(town),  DOWN(town), HOME(town), LONDON (town).
>  **3.** Words connected to **PEPPER** - RED (pepper), (pepper)CORN, (pepper)MINT, DOCTOR (pepper).
>  **4.** Words associated to **BLACK** - [LEWIS (Black)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Black), [GREEN (& Black's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_%26_Black%27s), [MARTIN (Black)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gay_Black), [DAVE (Black)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Black_(drummer))

And the overall connecting word is

> GHOST - (ghost)BUSTER, (ghost)TOWN, [(ghost) PEPPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_pepper), [BLACK (ghost)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_ghost_knifefish)

Why is this connected to Alex Trebek

> G.H.O.S.T is an acronym standing for "greatest host of syndicated TV"

Comment: Well this was certaintly not easy!

Comment: Not sure that last bit was what OP intended but I think I prefer your answer.

Comment: It is a reference to [James Holzhauer's final answer here](https://youtu.be/Svw6NCnuIkE?t=53).